# How to obtain the number of curves in a binary image using Python/OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, connected-components

I'm working in a method of counting the number of hats in a image.

I slice a binary image vertically in multiple sections, around 250/200, and then the counting of white elements (hats edges) is done in each os these sections. In the end of this process, the value obtained more times will be the result.

My struggle is that, often, the edges got some big gaps due to the binarization process. This way,  in many sections, those hats are not counted, which causes imprecisions in the final counting.

Does anyone can suggest a way of surpass this problem? I can post my code if is needed.

Thank you!

[image: This is the original image.]
[image: Here's the binary image which is divided in multiple vertical sections]

Comment: Binarize the image and use sketelization as explained here http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can :

- change the binarization process
  https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html
- use morphology transformation https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html

If the results aren't good, you need to try more complex process as Machine learning